# calculating correlations efficiently in R?

Tags: r, optimization, correlation

This is an optimization problem that I'm hoping you creative SO users may have an answer to.

I have a large matrix (5 million x 2) with two values: time and type. In essence, each "type"  is its own time series -- the below data represents three different time series (one for A, one for B, and one for C). There are 2000 different "types".

```
mat
     time type
[1,]  50   A
[2,]  50   A
[3,]  12   B
[4,]  24   B
[5,]  80   B
[6,]  92   B
[7,]  43   C
[8,]  69   C
```

What is the most efficient way for me to find the correlation between these 2000 time series? I am currently producing a matrix where there are different bins for each time where an event could have occurred, and I populate that matrix with how many events of each "type" occurred in that time slot. After populating that matrix, I loop over each pair of "type"s and find the correlations. This is extremely inefficient (~5 hours).

My whole problem could be solved if there exists a way to implement a `by='type'` feature in the `cor` function of R?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this

```
set.seed(1)
df <- 
data.frame(time = rnorm(15), type = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 5))

cor(do.call(cbind, split(df$time, df$type)))
         a        b        c
a  1.00000  0.27890 -0.61497
b  0.27890  1.00000 -0.78641
c -0.61497 -0.78641  1.00000
```

This approach assume that the number of observations per type is balanced.

Now, we can do a real test with 5 millions rows and 2000 differents types

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(time = rnorm(5e6), type = sample(rep(1:2000, each = 2500)))
system.time(cor(do.call(cbind, split(df$time, df$type))))
##  user  system elapsed 
## 6.387   0.000   6.391
```

Comment: this is a great solution but unfortunately my data set does not contain balanced number of observations. do you know whether there is a way to tweak it?